# Proof Combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

Proof that :

$P^n_r + P^{n+1}_r + P^{n+2}_r +...+ P^{n+m}_r =
 \frac1{r+1}(P^{n+m+1}_{r+1} - P^{n}_{r+1})$

**Attempt:**

LHS :

$r!C^{n}_r + r!C^{n+1}_r + r!C^{n+2}_r + ..... r!C^{n+m}_r$

$=r!(C^{n}_r + C^{n+1}_r + C^{n+2}_r + ..... C^{n+m}_r)$

$=r!C^{n+m+1}_{r+1}$

$=r!\frac{(n+m+1)!}{(r+1)!(n+m-r)!}$

$=\frac1{r+1}\frac{(n+m+1)!}{(n+m-r)!}$

$=\frac1{r+1}\frac{(n+m+1)!}{(n+m-r)!} \frac{(r+1)!}{(r+1)!}$

$=\frac1{r+1}\frac{(n+m+1)!}{(n+m-r)!(r+1)!} (r+1)!$

$=\frac1{r+1}C^{n+m+1}_{r+1}(r+1)!$

$=\frac1{r+1}P^{n+m+1}_{r+1}$

Need help stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, but you made a mistake going from the second line of your calculation to the third: it’s not true in general that

$$\sum_{k=n}^{n+m}\binom{k}r=\binom{n+m+1}{r+1}\;.$$

What is true is that

$$\sum_{k=\color{red}r}^{m+n}\binom{k}r=\binom{n+m+1}{r+1}\;.$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{k=n}^{n+m}\binom{k}r=\sum_{k=r}^{m+n}\binom{k}r-\sum_{k=r}^{n-1}\binom{k}r=\binom{n+m+1}{r+1}-\binom{n}{r+1}\;.$$

Comment: Hi could you explain the last line on how you split the summation. Is that Vandermonde's Identity. I have it in my notes but it looks  different there

Comment: @RStyle: No, it’s just grouping terms. Maybe it’s easier to see if you rewrite it as $$\sum_{k=r}^{m+n}\binom{k}r=\sum_{k=r}^{n-1}\binom{k}r+\sum_{k=n}^{m+n}\binom{k}r\;.$$ Does that help? (And yes, you need $r<n$ in order to make this split.) The first summation on the right contains the term with $k<n$, and the second contains the terms with $k\ge n$.

Comment: Additional: The question did state that r<n  if that helps in explaining to me

Comment: No lol i dun get the n-1 part. Is there an explanation through words :D

Comment: @RStyle: For simplicity let $a_k=\binom{k}r$. On the left we have $$a_r+a_{r+1}+\ldots+a_{m+n}\;.$$ On the right we simply split this as $$(a_r+\ldots+a_{n-1})+(a_n+\ldots+a_{m+n})\;.$$ We know the lefthand sum and the first sum on the right; they’re $\binom{n+m+1}{r+1}$ and $\binom{n}{r+1}$. Subtracting one from the other gives us the second sum on the left, which is the one that we really want.

Comment: @RStyle: You’re welcome!